# SoundManager, how to stop sound playing

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

I use simple SoundManager for play sounds from sounpool. My problem is, sound not stop playing when I exit from app, even I use `mySound.release();`.
Otherwise, everything works as it should, here is my code.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;

public class SoundManager {

private Context pContext;
private SoundPool mySound;

private float rate = 1.0f;
private float masterVolume = 1.0f;
private float leftVolume = 1.0f;
private float rightVolume = 1.0f;
private float balance = 0.5f;

// Constructor, setup the audio manager and store the app context
public SoundManager(Context appContext)
{
    mySound = new SoundPool(16, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);

  pContext = appContext;
}

// Load up a sound and return the id
public int load(int sound_id)
{
    return mySound.load(pContext, sound_id, 1);

}


// Play a sound
public void play(int sound_id)
{
    mySound.play(sound_id, leftVolume, rightVolume, 1, 0, rate);    
}   

// Set volume values based on existing balance value
public void setVolume(float vol)
{
    masterVolume = vol;

    if(balance < 1.0f)
    {
        leftVolume = masterVolume;
        rightVolume = masterVolume * balance;
    }
    else
    {
        rightVolume = masterVolume;
        leftVolume = masterVolume * ( 2.0f - balance );
    }

}


public void unloadAll()
{
    mySound.release();      
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `play()` return a `int StreamId`. You need to keep this StreamId on a variable and to call the stop method. For example:

Declare a Stream Id variable:

```
private int mStreamId;
```

Then, keep it when you start a new sound stream:

```
// Play a sound
public void play(int sound_id)
{
    mStreamId = mySound.play(sound_id, leftVolume, rightVolume, 1, 0, rate);    
}
```

So you can stop it doing:

```
mySound.stop(mStreamId);
```

Now you can stop your sound stream on the activities events `onStop`, `onPause` or where you want.

**EDIT:**

The best way to release your `SoundPool` resource is call `release` and set the reference to null *after* you stop playing the sound. For example:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSoundManager.unloadAll();
}
```

On your `SoundManager`, change your `unloadAll` method to:

```
public void unloadAll()
{
    mySound.release();
    mySound = null;    
}
```

> Note the following:
>
> **onPause** – is always called when the activity is about to go into the
>   background.
>
> **release:** releases all the resources used by the SoundPool
>
> **object null:** this SoundPool object can no longer be used (like @DanXPrado
>   said) so set it to null to help the Garbage Collector identify it as
>   reclaimable.

For more details, see [this tutorial about SoundPool](http://www.101apps.co.za/articles/using-android-s-soundpool-class-a-tutorial.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! does this only stop soundpool or does it also release all memory? what is correct way to release soundpool and all memory if use Soundmanager?

Comment: @nemo22898 , according to Android documentation: `It also releases any native resources associated with this stream.`. You can find the reference for the `stop()` method [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#stop%28int%29). Keep in mind that your SoundPool instance will be kept. Use `mySound.release()` to set your `mySound` reference to null.

Comment: @nemo22898 I edited my answer to explain how the best way to remove the `SoundPool` memory resources in your `SoundManager` class. If this answers your question, please accept the answer as correct.

Comment: Perfect! the last edit make the trick, Thanks! Now it clear all memory like i want it to do :)